# ¿Cómo funciona el directorio "assets" en Android cuando se actualiza la aplicación?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Estoy ofreciendo en mi aplicación una base de datos SQLite precargada desde un archivo con extensión `.db` que se encuentra en el directorio `assets`, [tal y como se explica en la documentación de Android](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate?hl=es-419).

El código para crear la base de datos es este:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DatabaseModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDatabase(application: Application?): AppDatabase {    
        return databaseBuilder(
            application!!, AppDatabase::class.java,
            "MyAPP"
        )
            .createFromAsset(DATABASE_PATH)
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .build()
    }

    // ...
}
```

Todo funciona bien. Pero ahora yo necesito, en una nueva versión de la aplicación, ofrecer una nueva versión de la base de datos precargada y para ello he creado un archivo distinto y con otro nombre en el directorio `assets` de la nueva versión de la aplicación.

Mi duda es: ¿si pongo otro archivo en `assets`, qué pasa con el antiguo, para el caso de aquellos usuarios que ya tienen instalada la aplicación? ¿Se borrará el antiguo, o tendrás dos archivos `.db`, el viejo y el nuevo?

¿En caso de que el viejo se quede, cómo debería borrarlo?

He estado mirando en la documentación de Android, y no explica con claridad qué pasa con los archivos que hay en `assets` cuando se actualiza una aplicación por ejemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Debido a que el directorio `/assets` es de "solo lectura", este directorio y su contenido no puede ser modificado, su contenido es el especificado en el proyecto y por lo tanto en el .APK o .AAB. En caso de una actualización, solo contendrá los archivos que se especifiquen en el proyecto.

> ¿si pongo otro archivo en assets, qué pasa con el antiguo, para el
> caso de aquellos usuarios que ya tienen instalada la aplicación? ¿Se
> borrará el antiguo, o tendrás dos archivos .db, el viejo y el nuevo?

En este caso, se actualizará tu aplicación con el nuevo archivo y tu actualización tendrá únicamente el nuevo archivo, la versión anterior de los archivos que se agregan dentro del directorio `/assets` no persiste.

Comment: Gracias. Esto aclara todo mi problema: *la versión anterior de los archivos que se agregan dentro del directorio `/assets` no persiste*. ¿Está documentado en alguna parte? Pregunto por curiosidad y porque siempre me gusta ir a la fuente. Tampoco me queda claro que pasa con el nuevo archivo en sí mismo en el caso de Room, dado que la base de datos se crea en efecto y es modificable. No sé si ese archivo (el nuevo) se borra una vez creada la BD o si sigue ahí, ocupando espacio. Creo que lo pregunté en el sitio en inglés, y no recibí respuesta...

Comment: Buena pregunta, hace tiempo traté de buscar información sobre esto ya que deseaba una solución en la cual pudiera subir una base de datos en /assets y encontré que entre actualizaciones no se agregaba nuevamente una base de datos, simplemente se eliminaba, por esta razón use [Android SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), pero esta solución en realidad creaba una copia a partir de la base de datos definida en /assets. Al parecer esto no esta documentado especificamente.

Comment: Con respecto a las bases de datos por ejemplo Room o SQLite, estas actualmente se crean dentro de la estructura de archivos que se crea al instalar la aplicación: \<package name>databases\, aquí se puede modificar la estructura de sus tablas y contenido.